# Excel: Why does regional settings change the way arguments are separated?

Tags: excel, regional-settings

Why does the U.S. english regional setting use colon(,) to separate arguments in formulas when other languages use semicolon(;)?

I've been discussing this with a colleague and we've have theorized that it's due to the way thousands are written in the US(1,000) compared to the way they're written in everywhere else. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Doubtfull, cause in that case a simple formula like `SUM` would give odd answers, p.e: `=SUM(1,2,3,400)`

Comment: Also consider that some (EU) countries, not all, use a comma for decimals ie 234,78 while others use 234.78